# Why is Kullback Leibler Divergence always positive?

Tags: intuition, entropy, information-theory, kullback-leibler

I know there have been mathematical treatments of this question on [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335197/why-kl-divergence-is-non-negative). What I'd like help with is my intuitive understanding though. Take the example given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Basic_example):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    x&0&1&2\\  \hline
P(x)&0.36&0.48&0.16\\  
   \hline
Q(x)&0.33&0.33&0.33\\  \hline
\end{array}$$

Where $D_{KL}(P||Q) = 0.0852996$ and $D_{KL}(Q||P) = 0.097455$. On the one hand, I think I understand that information is gained in both cases because the distribution changes, rather than remains the same (so some information has been gained about the likely value of $x$). But at the same time I can't shake the intuition that there should've been *information loss* for $D_{KL}(P||Q)$ because $Q(x)$ has greater entropy than $P(X)$. Can someone help to correct my intuitions? How is there information gain while entropy simultaneously increases?

Comment: I do not understand the close vote here. Clearly on-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intuitive understanding is somewhat subjective, but I can at least offer my perspective:

Kullback-Leibler divergence is a concept from Information Theory. It tells you how much longer --- how many bits --- on average are your messages going to be if you use a suboptimal coding scheme.

For every probability distribution, there is a lower bound on the average message length, and that is the entropy of the distribution. For the distribution $P$ from your Wikipedia example, it is

$$
- \sum_x P(x) \cdot \log_2 P(x) \approx 1.462
$$

That is, if you were to record realisations of random variables from that probability distribution, e.g. in a computer file, or transmit them over a limited-bandwidth channel, you'd need, on average, *at least* $1.462$ bits per realisation, no matter how sophisticated your coding is. Since in that distribution the case $x = 2$ is three times as probable as $x = 3$, it makes sense to use a shorter code for encoding the event $x=2$ than for encoding $x=3$. You could, for example, use the following encoding:

```
   x:    1       2       3
code:   01       1     001
```

The average message length with this code is $1.68$ bits, which is (of course!) more than the theoretical lower bound, but still better than an equal-length code, e.g.:

```
   x:    1       2       3
code:   01      10      11
```

which would need $2$ bits per event. You can construct more complex codes to encode sequences of events, but no matter what you do, you won't be able to beat the information-theoretical lower bound.

Now, for a different distribution, say $Q$, there are other encodings that approximate the best possible coding. The entropy of $Q$ from your example is $\approx 1.583$ bits. As approximations, both above codes are equally good, requiring on average $2$ bits per event, but more complex codes might be better.

However, what is better for encoding $Q$ is not necessarily better for encoding $P$. Kullback-Leibler divergence tells you how many bits does it costs you to use a coding optimised for transmitting/storing information on $Q$ if your true probability distribution is $P$. This measure cannot be negative. If it were, it would mean that you could beat the optimal coding for $P$ by using the coding optimised for $Q$ instead.

Indeed, the KL-divergence $D_{KL}(P||P) = 0$ (easy to show, because $\log(p(x)/p(x)) = \log(1) = 0$) tells you that encoding the probability distribution $P$ with a code optimised for that distribution incurs zero costs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gradually teaching myself information theory and this helped clarify KL divergence a bit. For anyone else reading this, I also found [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314227/does-it-make-sense-to-directly-subtract-the-entropy-values-of-two-distributions) to be helpful.

Comment: Also see the quotes in here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87182/what-is-the-role-of-the-logarithm-in-shannons-entropy/463828#463828